# Django manager queries don't work in a chain of queries. AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute <the manager method>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-managers

Problem: I've implemented a custom manager for a model with just one custom query set named `get_by_tag` and it's working fine if I use it this way:

```py
ViewStatistic.objects.get_by_tag('some-tag-name').filter(user=user_id)
```

But when I change the order of queries, in this way:

```py
ViewStatistic.objects.filter(user=user_id).get_by_tag('some-tag-name')
```

it doesn't work! and raises this error:

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_by_tag'
```

Am I missing something?! How can I do this in such a order?

P.S: The custom manager is something like this:

```py
class MyCustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_tag(self, tag_name):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__pk=tag_name)
        return super().get_queryset().filter(post__pk__in=posts)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use your queryset methods inside of queryset chain and not only directly after the manager, you should define them as methods of custom QuerySet class that you connect to a manager.

Two solutions are described in Django documentation **[Creating a manager with QuerySet methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#create-manager-with-queryset-methods)**.

**Common part** - a custom QuerySet class with queryset methods

```py
class MyCustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def get_by_tag(self, tag_name):
        return self.filter(post__pk__in=Post.objects.filter(tags__pk=tag_name))

    # more possible queryset methods ...
```

**A)** if your manager has only queryset methods and no other custom methods
    then you can create it simply from the QuerySet.

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyCustomQuerySet.as_manager()
```

**B)** if your manager need also other methods that do not return a queryset:

```py
class MyCustomManager(models.Manager):
    ...  # other methods

class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyCustomManager.from_queryset(MyCustomQuerySet)()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `ViewStatistic.objects` it returns the object of `<django.db.models.manager.Manager>`

In your case since it have derived class `MyCustomManager` having base class `models.manager`, so it return object of `<your_app.models.MyCustomManager>` which have `get_by_tag` function, and you can access `get_by_tag`.

For second case `ViewStatistic.objects.filter` return `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` object and ofcourse it hasn't no method named `get_by_tag` that's why you get AttributeError.

One more point related to queryset is
The **result of refining a QuerySet is itself a QuerySet**, so it’s possible to chain refinements together.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters

In your case get_by_tag return QuerySet further you performed .filter() operation, which is fine.

The django official documentation link can be followed related to models Manager and query for more details.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Do you mean it's not possible?

Comment: It is interesting that everything what you explained is correct, the only deficiency is an answer if a solution exists or not. I up-voted you, because it was useful for my answer and you are new and probably OP down-voted, because it was not useful for him.